# Ammonium sulphate precipitation assay pH dependence

Tags: biochemistry, proteins

In general does the pH effect the precipitation, e.g. would a pH of 6 cause less precipitation than pH 7.5. Or are they unrelated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would affect some proteins, but ammonium sulfate precipitation usually requires such large amounts of salt, that you would have to add a *lot* of base to adjust the pH.

When I have done ammonium sulfate precipitation, its to take a rough cut of proteins out of a whole cell/whole organ lysate - its more like a hammer than a pair of tweezers as far as protein purification is concerned.  I would rather use a charged plastic resin or a sizing column if I were to care about the isoelectric purification.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually trying to stop precipitation when incubating a protein in ammonium acetate, and I wondered if an acidic pH would reduce this. Do you have any suggestions

Comment: Do you know the pI of your protein? Proteins are least soluble at pH=pI.

Comment: also consider detergent - might the protein be a bit hydrophilic?

Comment: @Anake, I would look up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofmeister_series

Comment: the protein isn't hydrophobic, it is the ammonium's precipitating tendency as in the Hoffmeister series. I HAVE to use an ammonium salt, so the hoffmeister series cannot help me in that respect

Comment: So how did the pH change work?  Some proteins are just plain insoluable... is the solution quite dilute?  There are many possible things to try - its hard for us to guess.  maybe you can add a more complete description of your situation in the question...?